# Uso de Sesiones en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto *Web* e implemento *Sesiones* para el login de usuarios que cambia la vista dependiendo del rol del usuario, pero tengo el problema de que cambia la vista cuando es un solo usuario de todos los que hay, hice pruebas y los usuarios si existen en mi contexto de datos, pero como dije solo cambia la vista cuando es un usuario en especifico, cuando intento mandar datos de otro usuario aparece el error de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Parte de mi código es de esta forma

```
var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(obj.UserName) && 
           u.Password.Equals(obj.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

if(user != null){
     Session["UsuarioId"] = use.UsuarioId.ToString();
     Session["UserName"] = use.UserName.ToString();
     return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
}
else{
     ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid UserName or Password");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unas características a tener presente del  `@RenderBody()` :

- *RenderBody* **debe** estar presente en la vista de diseño padre , es en este punto donde falla , no tiene añadido el render en su (*Layout.cshtml*)
- *RenderBody* no incluye ningún parámetro

*Ejemplo básico*

*Layout.cshtml*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Texto del Padre</h2>
    @RenderBody() <!-- Llamada a Render , si no salta el error-->
</body>
</html>
```

*LoggedIn.cshtml*

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; /* Padre*/
}
 <p> Hola SOeS , Desde Vista Hija</p>
```

*Resultado*

> **Texto del Padre**
>
> Hola SOeS , Desde Vista Hija